# How to change URL address(details) by jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My English in not good. sorry.

URL address example:

example.com/action.php?id=1&name=JOHN&email=JONH@EXAMPLE.COM

I want change "name" only:

example.com/action.php?id=1&name=**JACK**&email=JONH@EXAMPLE.COM

***by Jquery or JavaScript Click Function.***

> I found a solution but I do not want to write everything again. I want
> to call name=JOHN and turn it into name=JACK.
>
> I do not want is:
>
> ```
> $('.element').click(function () {
> window.location = 'action.php?id=1&name=JACK&email=JONH@EXAMPLE.COM';
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string by a question mark (`?`) to get the parameters, then use the [`URLSearchParams` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) to parse it and [`URLSearchParams.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set) to set the `name` parameter to `"JACK"`:

```js
const url = "example.com/action.php?id=1&name=JOHN&email=JONH@EXAMPLE.COM";

const split = url.split('?');

const params = new URLSearchParams(split[1]);

params.set('name', 'JACK')

const result = split[0] + params.toString();
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your link is in an href in an `<a>` element .

You change change the href (or any attribute) value with the JQuery attr() function:

```
element.on(“click”, function () {
    $(this).attr(“href”, “ example.com/action.php?id=1&name=JACK&email=JONH@EXAMPLE.COM”);
});
```

Here element is the element on which you need to click, could also be a JQuery call $(“#elementID”). The this object refers in this context to the object being clicked on, so the element. If we wrap ‘this’ in a JQuery selector you can acces JQuery methods on that element, which would be .attr(). See the docs for further documentation: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I do not want to write everything again. I want to call JOHN and turn it into JACK.